# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found - Scanner/PriintWriter Issues

Tags: java

I want to bulk create some batch scripts using a csv and a txt file and I am getting an error when run. I commented the code so you should be able to ascertain my intentions from those notes. I am only writing more here because the bot is demanding that I keep writing more of an explaination before I can post. Once this red text box disappears I will stop writing and you can stop reading. I really hope you stopped reading already because this would either bore of frustrate me, thats for sure. Im starting to wonder if maybe I should start a new paragraph. Lets see if that helps.

I am getting the feeling that maybe using a different language for this would be more appropriate, but my experience is mostly limited to java and I am looking to get better with this language before moving on.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>       at printerscriptcreator.PrinterScriptCreator.main(PrinterScriptCreator.java:29)

```
public class PrinterScriptCreator {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File csvFile = new File("printers.csv");
        File txtFile = new File("xeroxTemplate.txt");
        Scanner csvScanner = new Scanner(csvFile);
        csvScanner.useDelimiter(",");
        Scanner txtScanner = new Scanner(txtFile);

        try{
            while(csvScanner.hasNext()){
                //create file with name from first csv cell
                File file = new File(csvScanner.next());
                //create FileWriter to populate the newly created file
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                //create PrintWriter to communicate with FileWriter
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                //copy first 7 lines from xeroxTemplate.txt
                for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
                    pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
                }
                //copy the next three cells from CSV into new file
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    pw.println(csvScanner.next());
                }
                //copy remaining lines from TXT to the new file
                while(txtScanner.hasNextLine()){
                    pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
                }
            }  
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Java is perfectly fine for this, no need to use another language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needed to create the txtScanner within the while loop so that it was recreated after each file creation. Otherwise it ran out of lines.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the right solution at all. You shouldn't have to do this. Recreating it reads the same lines over and over as well, right?

What does your input data look like?

Answer (score 0):

I notice, you check `hasNext()` once, and then grab `next()` three times.  You should probably put a conditional on `hasNext()` inside the for loop.

```
while(csvScanner.hasNext()){

    ...

        //copy the next three cells from CSV into new file
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            pw.println(csvScanner.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at printerscriptcreator.PrinterScriptCreator.main(PrinterScriptCreator.java:29)
```

This tells you what happened. One of your scanners was trying to pull a nextLine when it didn't have one, so it throws this exception.

It tells you PrinterScriptCreator.java:29. I don't have line numbers for your paste, but check line 29. Which line is that? My guess is its this one:

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
}
```

you're trying to pull 7 lines, and there aren't 7. So it throws exception.

You can try doing something like

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    if(txtScanner.hasNextLine()){
            pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Or you can try using a try-catch block to handle it. Either way, check your files and make sure they have the right data.

Comment: Needed to create the txtScanner within the while loop so that it was recreated after each file creation. Otherwise it ran out of lines.